# Date filter on Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have searched all over the web and I couldnt find anything that could properly help me with a code.

What I need is simple, but I still couldnt find it.

*The situation -->
Everyday, in my company, we receive a sales report accumulated by the actual month. 
As I have my own workbook, everyday I gotta filter only the information that I need and paste it on my workbook.
When it's monday we receive the information from friday and saturday sales together. 
I'm trying to code something to filter only yesterday, if it's not monday, and to filter friday and saturday, in case it's monday.

COLUMN D Contains the DATE I want to filter

As today is Thursday, I have set the if condition to vbthursday in order to test.

sabado = saturday;
friday = sexta;

```
Sub Data()
Dim yesterday As String


If Weekday(Date, vbThursday) = 1 Then

Dim sabado As String
Dim sexta As String
Range("D1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
sabado = Format(Date - 2, "dd/mm/yyyy")
sexta = Format(Date - 3, "dd/mm/yyyy")

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$11").AutoFilter Field:=4, Operator:= _
xlFilterValues, Criteria1:="=" & sabado, Criteria2:="=" & sexta



Else

Range("D1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
yesterday = Format(Date - 1, "dd/mm/yyyy")
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$11").AutoFilter Field:=4, Operator:= _
xlFilterValues, Criteria1:="=" & yesterday



End If
```

Actualy the if condition is working, it recognizes when it's vbMonday (in the test case, vbThursday) and when it's not. The else condition is also working too and it filters just as it should filter. The problem is that, when the macro enters the if condition, it does not filter properly. It runs throught the end and does not accuse any errors.

Somebody help :(

Comment: Try removing `"=" &` from all of your criteria settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
Sub Data()
    Dim datesToFilter()

    If Weekday(Date, vbMonday) = 1 Then
        datesToFilter = Array(Date - 2, Date - 3)
    Else
        datesToFilter = Array(Date - 1)
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$11").AutoFilter Field:=4, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=datesToFilter

End Sub
```